# What are single particle states used in occupation number representation for correlated systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interactions, many-body, second-quantization, strong-correlated

As I understand, the many-particle states are formed from the basis states of the single-particle vector spaces; occupation numbers then represent the number of particles in corresponding single-particle states. In presence of interaction (e.g., Coulomb type), there is no true single-particle state, is that correct? If so, ideally (without any approximation), for a many-body Hamiltonian (with interaction), what is the meaning of the occupation numbers?